# How to replace a varying number of strings on lines that match patterns

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, grep, sed

File1

```
<filename1.txt> stringA string1
<filename2.txt> stringA string2
<filename2.txt> stringB string3
```

File2

```
<filename1.txt>      words and symbols < $ stringA words and symbols 9 
<filename2.txt>      more words and symbols % @ stringA words and symbols stringB
```

File2 Transformed

```
<filename1.txt>      words and symbols < $ string1 words and symbols 9
<filename2.txt>      more words and symbols % @ string2 words and symbols string3
```

My approach is to loop through lines of File1 to set variables.  So for line 1, vars are set as:

```
filenamevar = <filename1.txt>
string_old_var = stringA 
string_new_var = string1
```

Then to grep lines which match filenamevar and string_old_var as input to sed. This is where I need help (unless you think there is a better way all together).

The closest so far is

```
grep -e "$filenamevar.*$string_old_var" File2.txt | sed s/$string_old_var/$string_new_var/ >> File2Transformed.txt
```

which works except the second line is output twice:

```
<filename1.txt>      words and symbols < $ string1 words and symbols 9 
<filename2.txt>      more words and symbols % @ string2 words and symbols stringB
<filename2.txt>      more words and symbols % @ stringA words and symbols string3
```

I have also tried

```
grep -e "$filenamevar.*$string_old_var" File2 | sed s/$string_old_var/$string_new_var/
```

and

```
sed -i s/$string_old_var/$string_new_var/ $(grep -e "$filenamevar.*$string_old_var" File2)
```

but neither produce desired results.

Here is the loop I am using

```
Numlines=$(grep "" -c File1.txt) 
for (( line=1; line<=$Numlines; line++ )) ; do 
 filenamevar=$(awk -v line=$line 'NR == line {print $1}' File1.txt) 
 string_old_var=$(awk -v line=$line 'NR == line {print $2}' File1.txt)
 string_new_var=$(awk -v line=$line 'NR == line {print $3}' File1.txt)
 # insert proper sed grep code to test here
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're determined to use a shell loop for this, you could do something like

```
while read -r fname patt repl; do 
  sed -i.bak "/$fname/s/^$patt/$repl/" File2
done < File1
```

but note that it may break in unexpected ways if any of your strings contain regex-special character sequences. Another option (with the same warning about special characters) would be something like

```
awk '{printf "/^%s/s/%s/%s/\n",$1,$2,$3}' File1 | sed -f- File2
```

which uses `awk` to format File1 into a sequence of commands which are then piped to `sed -f` to modify File2.

With GNU awk (aka `gawk`) which supports 2D arrays, you could just do:

```
$ gawk '
    NR==FNR {a[$1][$2] = $3; next} 
    $1 in a {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i = $i in a[$1] ? a[$1][$i] : $i} 
    1
  ' File1 File2
<filename1.txt> words and symbols < $ string1 words and symbols 9
<filename2.txt> more words and symbols % @ string2 words and symbols string3
```

or if you need to maintain the alignment, use the `index` function with `substr`:

```
$ gawk '
    NR==FNR {a[$1][$2] = $3; next}
    $1 in a {
      for(s in a[$1]) {
        mstart = index($0,s);
        if(mstart > 0) $0 = substr($0,1,mstart-1) a[$1][s] substr($0,mstart+length(s))}
    }
    1
  ' File1 File2
<filename1.txt>      words and symbols < $ string1 words and symbols 9
<filename2.txt>      more words and symbols % @ string2 words and symbols string3
```

---

Similar thing in vanilla awk, faking the 2D array with an FS-delimited string:

```
mawk '
  NR==FNR {a[$1 FS $2] = $3; next}
  {
    for(k in a) {
      split(k,b);
      if($1 == b[1]) {
        mstart = index($0,b[2]);
        if(mstart > 0) $0 = substr($0,1,mstart-1) a[k] substr($0,mstart+length(b[2]));
      }
    }
  }
  1 
' File1 File2
```

Comment: That looks really good. Can anyone offer a reason gawk is not installed on Ubuntu, by default?

Comment: @Insideup iirc Ubuntu has flipped between gawk and mawk a couple of times over the years / release cycles. However both are readily installable from the standard repositories (and there's no reason not to have both on a system - they don't conflict).

Comment: Ok.Thanks for the reassurance.

Comment: @Insideup please note that I have changed the solutions to use the string-based `index` function in place of the regular expression based `match`

Comment: Wow, that is really a great bit of content you provided here for solution to this type of problem.  What do you mean by "maintain the alignment"?

Comment: It works on my my sample great, but is not working in my real world situation. The output does not make the substitutions. I'm using the version that maintains alignment. In File1, the stringA and stringB have : and " in them, which seems to be the culprit. I am reading up on arrays to see how to fix that. But also when I have more replacements to be made (such as 4 instead of 2 in the second line), it gets the 1st and 3rd correct but the 2nd and 4th reversed.

Comment: I have tried all solutions (removing : and " for each), but unfortunately I haven't found how to make t them work.

Comment: Please see my 1 comment above, @steeldriver

Comment: @Insideup I can't really comment on why the above solutions don't work on your actual data - you would need to provide an actual minimal testable example

Comment: Okay, @steeldriver I have edited my post with more realistic example files and desired result

Comment: @Insideup there don't appear to be any string matches between your `betterfiles` - ones uses `style:name` and the other uses `style-name`

Comment: oh no .. I fixed that at one point, but must have lost it somehow. Will fix.

Comment: Too many trees to see the forest. That fixed it. I have edited the original post, removing the ```betterfiles``` as I think its clearer overall without. Thank you so much for the help, @steeldriver.